# Insert image into row within column in MySQL table rather than as an individual column?

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I am incredibly new to PHP and mySql but am trying to learn for a project. I have followed this tutorial http://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/ to be able to upload images as columns in a blob table in a MySQL database with rows such as image size, id, etc.

I have a separate data table where I create columns for individual user accounts (each account has a row for username, password, etc). I have created a row in these columns to store a blob.

I do not need all the rows that the tutorial created for their images (image_type, size, etc) but really just need the image source (the image row). I need to insert this image into the ROW for images in my accounts column (depending on which account is signed in), NOT have new columns be created for each image. I do not know how to go about this with the code I have. Here my JavaScript for my HTML forms:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    //To transfer clicks to divs
     $(".upload-button").on('click', function() {
       $("#file").click();
    });
    $(".save").on('click', function() {
       $(".submit").click();
    });


        $("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {

        }
        });
        }));

        // Function to preview image after validation
        $(function() {
        $("#file").change(function() {
         // To remove the previous error message
        var file = this.files[0];
        var imagefile = file.type;
        var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
        if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2])))
        {
        $('.userimg').attr('src','noimage.png');

        return false;
        }
        else
        {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
        });
        });
        function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $("#file").css("color","green");
        $('#image_preview').css("display", "block");
        $('.userimg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('.userimg').attr('width', '250px');
        $('.userimg').attr('height', '230px');
        };
});
```

Which then references upload.php, which is where changes need to be made:

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES["file"]["type"]))
{
$validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$maxsize = 99999999;
$temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$file_extension = end($temporary);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < $maxsize)//Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
&& in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br/><br/>";
}
else
{
if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " <span id='invalid'><b>already exists.</b></span> ";
}
else
{
$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
$targetPath = "images/".$_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored

 $size = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
 /*** assign our variables ***/
 $type = $size['mime'];
 $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
 $size = $size[3];
 $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];



 /*** check the file is less than the maximum file size ***/
 if($_FILES['file']['size'] < $maxsize )
 {
 /*** connect to db ***/
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sqlserver", 'username', 'password');

 /*** set the error mode ***/
 $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 /*** our sql query ***/
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO imageblob (image_type ,image, image_size, image_name) VALUES (? ,?, ?, ?)");

 /*** bind the params ***/
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $type);
 $stmt->bindParam(2, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
 $stmt->bindParam(3, $size);
 $stmt->bindParam(4, $name);

 /*** execute the query ***/
 $stmt->execute();
 $lastid = $dbh->lastInsertId(); 
 //Move uploaded File
 move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ; // Moving Uploaded file
 if(isset($lastid))
 {
 /*** assign the image id ***/
 $image_id = $lastid;
     try {
     /*** connect to the database ***/
     /*** set the PDO error mode to exception ***/
     $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     /*** The sql statement ***/
     $sql = "SELECT image, image_type FROM imageblob WHERE image_id=$image_id";

     /*** prepare the sql ***/
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

     /*** exceute the query ***/
     $stmt->execute(); 

     /*** set the fetch mode to associative array ***/
     $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     /*** set the header for the image ***/
     $array = $stmt->fetch();
     /*** check we have a single image and type ***/
     if(sizeof($array) == 2)
     {
         //To Display Image File from Database
         echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $array['image'] ).'"/>';

     }
     else
     {
     throw new Exception("Out of bounds Error");
     }
     }
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
     echo $e->getMessage();
     }
     catch(Exception $e)
     {
     echo $e->getMessage();
     }
     }
     else
     {
     echo 'Please input correct Image ID';
     }
 }
 else
 {
 /*** throw an exception is image is not of type ***/
 throw new Exception("File Size Error");
 }
}
}
}
else
{
echo "<span id='invalid'>***Invalid file Size or Type***<span>";
}
}

?>
```

I have tried trying to cut out references to image size, type, etc as I feel these are unnecessary, however this created errors. I have poured over other SO posts but can't understand how to simply insert an image into a row within an EXISTING column in mysql data base. I can only create new columns for images.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `mysql` and `sql-server` are not the same thing. You are using `mysql` (`new PDO("mysql:..`). Just because you name your database `sqlserver` does not make it a `sql-server`.

Comment: If you want to add the image to an existing row, you need to change your `INSERT INTO ...` query to a `UPDATE ...` query. In that `UPDATE` query you need to use a `WHERE columnName = value`. The `columnName = value` is where you would specify your logged in user.

Comment: The above tutorial clearly shows you how t insert an image as blob to a table. Now, you have to insert it to a different table. All you need to do is to apply what you have learnt from the tutorial. If you do not understand what it is doing, then go back to the tutorial and re-read it again or ask a specific question relating to what you do not understand. But pls do not ask us to rewrite a tutorial's code to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, storing files in a database is [not](http://blog.lick-me.org/2013/01/repeat-after-me-mysql-is-not-a-filesystem/) usually [recommended](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-a-bad-design-to-store-images-as-blobs-in-a-database) for various reasons. While there are some exceptions to that rule, you should be sure that this is the best solution for you.

Instead, first ask why you want to do this and why storing files on disk and then tracking the *filename* in your database is not the preferred solution. Once you can justify your use case, (**if** you can justify your use case) then you should be asking how to implement it.